# Edit: always getting null pointer exception for Platform.getBundle("some_plugin_id")

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, manifest.mf

```
private void checkDependencyInBundle() throws Exception {


    try { 
      Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin name from Maniftst.MF file mentioned in Bundle-Symbolic name");


      System.out.println("From checkDependency Method:::" + bundle);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printstacktrace();
    }


  }
```

// Pleas help if possible

//Hi All added the stacktrace below

/* java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundles(InternalPlatform.java:232)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundle(InternalPlatform.java:222)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle(Platform.java:1424)
*/

Comment: PLease add the stacktrace

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Platform.getBundle works fine provided the plug-id id is correct and the plug-in is actually in the currently running RCP. Don't forget that when you test your plug-in using "Run As > Eclipse Application" the set of plug-ins is the list specified in the Run Configuration (which may be different from the Eclipse you are using)

Comment: Please share more details (like stacktrace)

Comment: That looks like you are probably not running this in a plug-in. Platform.getBundle (and must other Eclipse APIs) will only work when run in a plug-in installed in Eclipse or an Eclipse RCP.

Comment: Hello Greg,
thanks for your reply am running this code in plugin only here is the pathin plugin->src->java class 
but still am not able to solve this error

Comment: The path is not really relevant. Show us the MANIFEST.MF of your plug-in. For testing you must run it using "Run As > Eclipse Application" - are you doing that?